# Outputting variable content to React Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have this:

```
let arr = [
  { name:"string 1"},
];
```

and I find the value using this:

```
let obj = arr.find(o => o.name === 'string 1');
```

then I am trying to output `obj` to my react component.

```
class Links extends Component {
render() {
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <Link to="/" className="navbar-brand">
            { obj } 

            </Link>
```

It is says `Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {name})`

I am new to react so not sure how to do this properly... Thanks 4 the help :)

Comment: do you want the value of obj rendered, or the obj itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is, you are tring to print an object which is not allowed.

If you try running this program:

```
let arr = [
  { name:"string 1"},
];
let obj = arr.find(o => o.name === 'string 1');
console.log(obj); //{name: "string 1"}
```

You will find that obj is an object which has a key value pair.
So, what you need to do is to replace `{obj}` with `{obj.name}`